# What are "consecutive days"?

Tags: support, consecutive-days

What does the expression "consecutive days" mean with respect to badges?

Does it mean that you have to revist the site within 24 hours? Or does it allow that you might visit in the morning and the next day just before you finish work — e.g. over 24 hours, but say under 26 hours?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A day is defined as the hours between 00:00:00Z and 23:59:59Z (ie- UTC).  Consecutive days are between those hours on immediate subsequent calendar days.

If Visit 1 happens at 13:24Z on Aug 31 and Visit 2 happens at 8:41Z on Sep 1 then you have visits on 2 consecutive days.

If Visit 1 happens at 23:50Z on Aug 31 and Visit 2 happens at 00:35 on Sep 1 then you have visits on 2 consecutive days.

If Visit 1 happens at 13:24Z on Aug 31 and Visit 2 happens at 8:41Z on Sep 2 (with no visits between 00:00:00-23:59:59Z on Sep 1) then you do not have visits on 2 consecutive days and the "visits on consecutive days count" for badges is reset.

Answer (score 3):

To have the days counted as consecutive days you have to visit at least once during each SO/SE day (00.00-23.59 UTC).

Comment: So it does not take into account of the time zone and the human concept of a day (i.e. a working day). So to get the the badge you need to visit the site under 24 hours - lets everty say 23 hrs. Then over the perioid of 30 days you would have visited the site over 30 days!

Comment: If you are European (like from Scotland :) it is very close to the real day. Right now, for me the new day starts at 02.00 which is close enough to midnight that it doesn't matter.

Comment: @EdHeal: Not quite. You only need to visit the site once per day, it's just that the days are according to UTC time, not your local time.